# Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

When I'm submitting the image, it shows the following error:

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

I do not know, where the mistake is.

This is my controller named `ProductController`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'brand' => 'required',
        'detail' => 'required',
        'size' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
    ]);
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $new_name = rand().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
    $form_data = array(
        'image' => $new_name,
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'size' => $request->input('size'),
        'type' => $request->input('type'),
        'price' => $request->input('price'),
        'detail' => $request->input('detail'),
        'brand' => $request->input('brand'),
    );

    Product::create($form_data);
    return redirect()->route('product.index')->withSuccess('Done');
}
```

The error occours on this line: `$new_name = rand().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();`

This is my form from where I am submitting the image:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="{{ route('product.store') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="user-box">
                            <input type="text" name="name" required="">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-box">
                            <input type="text" name="brand" required="">
                            <label>Brand</label>
                            @error('brand')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-box">
                            <input type="text" name="price" required="">
                            <label>Price</label>
                            @error('price')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-box" style=" border-bottom: 1px solid white">


                            <span style="font-weight: bold; color: white; font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 30px ">Size</span>
                            <select name="size" id="size" style="width: 40px; font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 20px ">
                                <option value="50  ML">50 ML</option>
                                <option value="100  ML">100 ML</option>
                                <option value="200  ML">200 ML</option>
                                <option value="500  ML">500 ML</option>
                                <option value="1 L">1 L</option>
                                <option value="4 L">4 L</option>
                                <option value="10 L">10 L</option>
                                <option value="20 L">20 L</option>
                            </select>
                            @error('size')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-box">
                            <input type="text" name="type" required="">
                            <label>Type</label>
                            @error('type')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-box">
                            <input type="text" name="detail" required="">
                            <label>Detail</label>
                            @error('detail')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-box">
                            Image<input type="file" name="image" required="">
                            <label>Image</label>
                            @error('image')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <button class="a" id="a" value="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>

                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag like below:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="{{ route('product.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Sure, Is your problem gone?

Answer (score 3):

your server is not receiving the file that you are uploading,

Try adding the enctype='multipart/form-data' to the form in blade file.

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="{{ route('product.store') }}" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```